# On hover how to change div border

Tags: javascript, css, border

Hello everybody
I have a div on mouse hover i want to change border of div.And on more thing  id is Changed dynamically. Please provide me any help for this
Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried that is not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may this help you

```
 <div onmouseover="somefunction(<?php echo $divid ?>)"> </div>


<script>
function somefunction(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.border="10px #FF0000 solid";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this not do the trick?

```
div {}
div:hover {border:1px solid #000000;}
```

Comment: Great answer, keep it simple!

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to work in all browsers you'll need to use javascript rather than the pseudo class `:hover`. Older versions or IE do not like :hover on elements that are not anchor tags.

So you could just provide a class to the div and then use jQuery to easily select it. This is probably the easiest way.

Something like:

```
$(function(){

  $('.yourclass').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function(){
       $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    }
  );

});
```

Where the class hovered contains the css for your hovered state.

If you want to change the ID on hover you could add that into the code above with `$(this).attr('id','newID');`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> function changeBoder(divID){ alert(divID); document.getElementById(divID).style.border-color="#0000ff;"; } </script>'

Comment: I m trying this by javascript. I m beginner so i dont know the syntax of javascript exact.please reply

Answer (score 3):

CSS provides the :hover selector that should work on the div.

for example:

```
div:hover { border: 1px solid #454545; }
```

As for changing the the id dynamically I would use jQuery

```
jQuery(this).attr("id",newId);
```

If you post specific code I can help with the syntax for your specific case...

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBoder(divID){ alert(divID);
          document.getElementById(divID).style.border-color="#0000ff;";
        
        }
 
 </script>`

Comment: Have a look for this code.i m trying this by using javascript.divID is dynamic .please reply its very very urgent.